# Automatically connect duplicate Windows RDP users to an existing, shared session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services

When a new Remote Desktop client connects to an RD server with a username that's already connected, Remote Desktop Services normally does one of two things:

- Disconnect the previous remote, and connect the new remote to the old session (`fSingleSessionPerUser` = 1), or
- Create a new session for that user (`fSingleSessionPerUser` = 0)

How can Windows be configured/forced/hacked to automatically connect new RDP clients having the same username to the existing session, as [shadow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shadow)s?

`Shadow -> Full Control without user's permission` is necessary but not sufficient.  Would `Termsrv.dll` have to be patched?

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is a perfectly valid goal, and a frequent unanswered question in other forums.

Answer (score 0):

> How can Windows be hacked to automatically connect new RDP clients [...] as shadows?

It can not. Shadowing needs more extensive rights and a completely different connection method.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the following Group Policy:

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections > **Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session**

> This policy setting allows you to restrict users to a single Remote
> Desktop Services session.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, users who log on remotely by using
> Remote Desktop Services will be restricted to a single session (either
> active or disconnected) on that server. If the user leaves the session
> in a disconnected state, the user automatically reconnects to that
> session at the next logon.